# gmap4rails - can't find file underscore / Gmaps is not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails, gmaps4rails2

I am following the simple tutorial here: https://github.com/JonKernPA/gmaps

I keep getting the error:

```
couldn't find file 'underscore'
    (/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:16)
```

with the following line highlighted:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

I tried following the suggestions posted in 
[Gmaps is not defined in rails 4 + gmaps4rails 2.0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19905972/gmaps-is-not-defined-in-rails-4-gmaps4rails-2-0-3)

and I get the same error with the error with the same line highlighted. 
When I try to remove the line

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

from application.html.erb, I get the error "Gmaps not found"

Any help appreciated, thanks.
Github link: https://github.com/chiefkikio/circus/

Answer (score 16):

Found a solution. Had to install gem 'underscore-rails' and then bundle it and restart the rails server.

Answer (score 1):

Not a tutorial project, but I use `gem 'underscore-rails'` (cf https://rubygems.org/gems/underscore-rails) to satisfy gmaps4rails' dependence.

Answer (score 0):

The minified version of Underscore has this line at the end of the file:

//# sourceMappingURL=underscore-min.map

Chrome's developers tools will try to download underscore-min.map when encountering this line. Users won't see this error, unless they open developer tools.

If you want to get rid of this error, either add underscore-min.map to your project (https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore-min.map) or remove that line from underscore.min.js

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the issue and this is what was the reason for me:
The order of required files in my application.js was wrong. I required 
`//= require_tree .` before gmaps. And since I didn't wait until page load in my controller_name.js file, it was loaded first, trying to use Gmaps before the latter was defined.. I thought it might help, but.. I run into another couple issues with ".. is not defined". After small research here is the solution:
wrap you whole custom js in callback for window.load event. I used it with this line:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", callback)
```

Hope this will help